# No VGA signal after installing ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, display, vga

I installed ubuntu server 14.04.2 couple days ago on an oldish computer ([This one](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-a6000-Desktop-PC-series/3436774/model/3461451)). And i was able to install it just fine and the VGA seemed to work after i booted it up for the first time. Now i come back and theres no vga signal apparently. I tested the monitor with other computers and its working fine.

i cant even see the splash screen to get into BIOS for christ sake, which makes me think its not software related but i cant be sure.

How do i diagnose the issue?

i have tested using both the DVI and VGA output on this computer on a separate monitor (nothing came up). I have also tested the VGA input on the first monitor by plugging it into my laptop which instantly brought the signal up on it. It has to the be the video output of the computer.

i disconnected power, took out the battery and waited 3 minutes, then put it back in. The problem persists, i still cant even get it to show the splash screen. I even measured the batteries voltage with a multimeter and got just over 3 volts.

Comment: yes, i have tested using both the DVI and VGA output on this computer on a separate monitor. I have also tested the VGA input on the first monitor by plugging it into my laptop which instantly brought the signal up on it. It has to the be the video output of the computer.

Comment: sorry about that, i have updated the post.

Comment: Try turning the machine off -> disconnect it from the wall -> remove the CMOS battery for a few minutes -> put the battery back in -> reconnect the cables -> test.

Comment: this is a desktop PC, does it have a CMOS battery?

Comment: If it has a BIOS that has a clock then yes. Pull the side off your PC and you'll see a shiny coin battery :)

Comment: ill try to remove the battery and then put it back in. Does the CMOS Battery running low mean it can still power up?

Comment: You must disconnect the power cable (or at least switch it off at the mains) before removing the battery. Usually, a low CMOS battery will display symptoms of your computer forgetting the date/time or any custom BIOS settings you have applied. Your symptoms, IMO, aren't a low battery problem, but removing the battery will force your BIOS to forget any settings and can often resolve some problems like what you're experiencing.

Comment: i disconnected power, took out the battery and waited 3 minutes, then put it back in. The problem persists, i still cant even get it to show the splash screen.

Comment: i also measured the cmos battery with a multimeter and it read just over 3 volts.